# C++: Make all template specialization friend

Tags: c++

Let's say I have some template class which needs an access to private fields of any its specialization:

```
template<std::size_t SIZE> class Buffer {
    template<std::size_t N> friend class Buffer<N>;

    ...
};
```

This code doesn't compile:

```
<source>:4:42: error: specialization of 'template<long unsigned int SIZE> class Buffer' must appear at namespace scope
    4 |     template<std::size_t N> friend class Buffer<N>;
      |                                          ^~~~~~~~~
```

How can I achieve this behavior?

Comment: It would be much simpler to just make all the members public. That’s effectively what making every template instance a friend does, since users can write specializations of your friend template.

Answer (score 2):

Consider the same declaration without the `friend` specifier:

```
template<std::size_t N> class Buffer<N>;
```

That is not a declaration of a (primary) class template `Buffer`, but a declaration of a partial specialization of `Buffer`.

A declaration of the (primary) class template itself looks like this:

```
template<std::size_t N> class Buffer;
```

So add the `friend` specifier to that and you friend the class template itself, which implies friending all specializations of it:

```
template<std::size_t SIZE> class Buffer {
    template<std::size_t N> friend class Buffer;

    //...
};
```